# How to upgrade the classifier to the latest version of scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a big trained TfidfVectorizer dumped with [joblib.dump](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.dump.html).
It was created on my laptop with scikit-learn version 0.18. When I'm trying to put it to my server where the newest version of scikit-learn 0.18.1 is installed I'm getting warned with the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py:315: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfTransformer from version 0.18 when using version 0.18.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py:315: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfVectorizer from version 0.18 when using version 0.18.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
```

Is there a natural way to upgrade my TfidfVectorizer to prevent any problems?

Should I better uninstall scikit-learn 0.18.1 and install version 0.18 to the server instead?

Comment: I don't think there are migration tools. If you want to be safe, use the same version or better if possible: upgrad and re-fit. If you got some time, check the source-changes between the versions in regards to serializing your classifier and you might reason about possible consequences.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you should install the same version on your server as you used for development, best practice is to use a `requirements.txt` for all the requirements of your project and install a new environment on your server using `conda` or `virtualenv`, this will save you the problems of manually setting this stuff up.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) link gives you instructions on how to upgrade.

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

The above command should upgrade whatever your current version of scikit is to the latest version. Depending on what you are doing with the tfidf vectorizer, you may or may not have issues; I would recommend staying updated with new releases. So, you would be better off making sure your server and computer both run the latest sci-kit.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't solve my problem. 
I've trained that tfidf vectorizer on a huge 12Gb corpus. The whole my project depends on it so it's critical to have it working without any mistakes. I'd rather prefer to stay at the old version of scikit-learn than to get unpredictable results with the latest one. Is there a link how to specify the version to install?

Comment: @ArtemNepo Check the python docs. It's something like ```pip install scikit-learn=0.18``` (after deleting)

Comment: @sascha Thank you. `pip install scikit-learn==0.18` resolved my problem.  I'll wait for example for version 0.19 as for a major upgrade and then I'll re-fit my vectorizer but at this moment I'd prefer to stick to the 0.18

Comment: @sascha Yeah, I misunderstood the question. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to circumvent this problem by first updating sklearn to the latest version, then loading the pickled objects with joblib.load and dumping it with joblib.dump. When I've done this, I no longer receive a warning.

Comment: I did the same but I'm not sure it is the correct solution. If the unpickling is unreliable this migrations is not safe. I suppose the real fix is something like this: unpickle with the old version and save to safe format (csv, npy). Now update the version, load the data and reserialize with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall and reinstall the latest Scikit (or upgrade to the latest version) .
And then train the model once again and that will generate a new joblib model. This will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

you should install the version of scikit that your project use.

first uninstall scikit :

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
```

then install correct version like that:

```
pip install -v scikit-learn==0.18
```